# Laravel return relationship object with data from pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have the following tables setup in my application:

- `user`
- `job_title`
- `job_title_user` (pivot table)

I have setup a relationship model for job titles in the `user` model, like so:

```
/**
 * The job titles that belong to the user.
 *
 * @return Object
 */
public function jobTitles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User\JobTitle');
}
```

I want to be able to select multiple rows from the user table, whilst joining on the `job_title_id` field from the `job_title_user` table.

So basically i'm looking to do a select on the user table (selecting multiple users), but also select which job titles the user has assigned to them.

The other problem is that I want to send the returned data to jSon, like this:

```
    return response()->json([
        'rows'    => $rows
    ]);
```

**How can I achieve this?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because of the BelongsToMany relationship you've defined, Laravel will automatically query the job_title_user table.

In other words, just use

```
@foreach ($user->jobTitles as $jobTitle)
    {{ $jobTitle->id }}
@endforeach
```

in your template to access it. See also the [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables) on pivot tables.

Comment: It's worth to note that if you're planning to do this on a range of users, to avoid the `n+1` problem, use the `with()` method on the initial query. I.e. `User::with('jobTitles')->all()` (maybe it's `User::with('job_titles')->all()`, I don't remember..)

Comment: This gives out the error: `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$jobTitles`